# Possible to Write a Bot Without a Server?

Tags: server, bots

I don't have my own web server.  Is it possible to write a bot that will fill out a webpage form without a server?  If not, can I use my localhost to do it?  What are my [free] options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible, you can just run the bot using your own machine as a server, as long as it has an internet connection. The only catch with this is that you'll obviously have to keep your machine on and connected to keep the bot running.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your trying to do, but you can use XAMPP to host a local server on your computer.